# Assign an image to a taxonomy in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I am trying to get a different icon to appear next to an event in Wordpress. I am use the "The Event Calendar" plugin and the events are stored as taxonomies. I have three taxonomies. "Tax1", "Tax2" and "Tax3".

I cannot seem to figure out how to call to check what the taxonomies are and assign an icon to each one. Here is what I have so far. 

    " title="" rel="bookmark">

```
<?php $taxonomy_exist = taxonomy_exists( 'Tax2' ); ?>


<?php if(is_tax($taxonomy_exist)) { ?>
        <p>working!!!!!!!!!!</p>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <img class="cat-icon" src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Heart.png" />
                                        <?php } ?>


    <?php $title = get_the_title($event); ?>
      <?php if (strlen($title) > 30) { ?>
         <?php echo mb_strimwidth($title, 0, 30, '...'); ?>
      <?php } else { ?>
         <?php echo $title ?>
      <?php }?></a></span><!--.event-title-->
```

[image]

So it is getting to the if statement and failing, showing the heart icon. How can I see if it is part of the "Tax2" taxonomy?

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:
is_tax() accepts taxonomy names as a first argument. But you put $taxonomy_exist parameter which is boolean. (true/false). Of course it should not work and always return zero. Because there is not any taxonomy called "true" or "false".

Problem 2: Are you sure that tax1, tax2 and tax3 are taxnomies? may be they are terms? if they are terms then i will add a solution code as an update to this answer. If they are taxonomies, then i don't see any logic there. Because taxonomies are not objects to be related to posts. Taxonomy is name of categorization, terms are member elements of those taxonomies.

Comment: I think that is correct. They are terms not Taxonomies. Sorry new to the taxonomy thing in Wordpress and didn't have my terminology correct.

Comment: then you just need to use has_category() function (or has_taxonomy, it depends on which taxonomies you are using for terms: tax1,tax2,tax3) instead of is_tax.   if (has_category('tax1',$event)) echo 'working';